# Which is the recommended UIViewController override method where constraints can be initialised?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating UI programatically. I am initialising the UI and adding it as subview in `loadView()` method. I have categorized method like:

```
initUI()
initConstraints()
initStyle()
```

I am looking for correct override method where each of these can be placed in the `UIViewController`.

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    initUI()
}

func initUI() {
    view = UI.view(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

func initConstraints() {  // Where to place this?
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([]) // ..
}
```

Where to place `initConstraints()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is that the views controlled by the constraints have been added to the view hierarchy before the constraints are created.

If you are creating and activating the constraints in `initConstraints()`, you should call it immediately after adding the views to the view hierarchy which is done in `loadView()` or `viewDidLoad()`.

You can either call `initConstraints()` at the end of `initUI()` or after the call to `initUI()`.

Answer (score 1):

In you constraint setting function, remember to call,
`scrollView.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.
Just after you did `view.addSubview(scrollView)`, you can call you constraints function.

But yes if you want them to change later, you should set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.